# autoloaded classes not being found when instantiated via __get()

Tags: php

This is my code that autoloads and calls/instantiates my classes

```
public function __get($name)
{
    $classname = '\\System\\' . ucfirst($name);

    if (property_exists($this, '_' . $name))
        $this->{'_' . $name} = new $classname();
    else
        echo $name . ' isn\'t a valid property.';
}


private function boot()
{echo "<pre/>";
    spl_autoload_register(null, false);

        if (function_exists('__autoload'))
            spl_autoload_register('__autoload');

        spl_autoload_register(array($this, 'libraries'));
var_dump($this->helper);
        //$this->configuration();
}
```

When I call `$this->helper` I get this error

```
Fatal error:  Call to a member function test() on a non-object in (...)
```

So my question is, are the classes still being loaded when the `__get()` method is called?

And yes, the method `test()` does exist in my `Helper` class

Comment: This must be hell to maintain, when it's a fully grown project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `$this->_helper->test();` as your code is doing: `$this->{'_' . $name} = new $classname();`

Your magic method is re-instantiating the class each time it's called. You should have it check if it's `null` first:

```
if (property_exists($this, '_' . $name) && $this->{'_' . $name} !== null)
```

Comment: would `is_null()` work the same? because I want to instantiate if the property isn't null right?

Comment: Yes, `is_null` has the same effect.